# Backed up toilets

Tags: bathroom

My toilets keep clogging. I have city sewer, no one is flushing non toilet paper items, I had them unclothed by a plumber last year then again in May of this year. The house was built in the 60s but I bought it 2 years ago.

Comment: maybe your pipes have a bad case of the bends

Answer (score 2):

You need to determine whether the problem is with the toilet or the plumbing.

If everything else drains fine, and you can unclog the toilets with a plunger -- even if it's difficult to do so, if you get good flushing after that -- then you probably want to look at replacing the toilets. There are economical toilets with large diameter (e.g., 2.5") traps that are "good flushers".

If other drains are sluggish as well as the toilets, and no amount of plunging will improve things, then the problem is probably with your drain plumbing clogging easily, which can be due to small diameter, long runs, poor venting, and rusty scaly pipe. In the 60s, cast iron and galvanized steel were popular. In a 60s house I used to live in, I replaced all that with PVC and never another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had several homes built in this era the drain lines are usually cast and were put together with okum packed into the flange and a lead seal. Over the years these joints start failing and tree roots or other plant roots from hedges get in the pipes. I use a large drain augger to cut the roots until it becomes two often then replace the main line.